# syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can any one explain me what's my problem :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values('SELECT c.value FROM custom_values c,
time_entries p, custom_fields cf  where  c.customized_type = 'TimeEntry' 
and p.id = c.customized_id and c.custom_field_id = cf.id 
and cf.type = 'TimeEntryCustomField' and cf.name = 'Reference TS Client' 
and p.id = '+ log.user.id.to_s +' ;')
```

I get this error just for "c.customized_type". What can be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are closing the String with ' and semicolon , try this one:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("SELECT c.value FROM custom_values c,
time_entries p, custom_fields cf  where  c.customized_type = 'TimeEntry' 
and p.id = c.customized_id and c.custom_field_id = cf.id 
and cf.type = 'TimeEntryCustomField' and cf.name = 'Reference TS Client' 
and p.id = ?", log.user.id.to_s)
```

Comment: You have a typo ;) ActiveRecoed -> ActiveRecord